# Android Application or Mobile Web Application

Tags: android, html

I am trying to generate a tourist application for my final year project, which is a tourist application for the Olympic Games in London. the thing which is very confusing for me is that , I really dont know if I have to generate it in Android as a standalone application or should I generate it in Spring+HTML5 as Mobile Web Application???
please let me know your ideas.
the requirements are:

1. having the games Venues
2. games schedules
3. lots of google maps as how to get to the games and venues
4. uplodading pictures
5. checking the undergrounds and transportation in london

please let me know if you have any idea,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can fit nicely all that stuff to html and make it usable as well then you should go for html since this move would allow the usage of your web app not only on android but on other mobile devices.

Another thing to consider is the limitations which comes from the web interface. What I would do in your place is that i would create a prototype of an android application and a prototype of the web application, then you compare the too ,pros and cons and after the evaluation of the results you will be able to decide which prototype you should develop further more to bring it to its final form.

Anyway if you only need to support only one platform then I think the android application would be a good choice.

Comment: I know that OP didn't want this functionality, so I'm just saying for future reference: By having a web app you can't provide notifications which are available to you on a native platform. - or I may be living in a lala land for not knowing that this may as well be possible...